# Splitting up a dynamically changing linked list with OpenMP using tasks

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I have a theoretical OpenMP question for you all.
Imagine I do the following:

```
 #pragma omp parallel
 {
    #pragma omp single
    {
    while (!empty(linkedList)) {
      #pragma omp task
              doWork();
      }
    }
 }
```

What happens if doWork() adds elements back into the list?
My worry is that the single thread that is spinning of the tasks will terminate before the threads doing the tasks can finish. This might mean that any elements that gets added back onto the list by the doWork function are missed. Does anybody know how this works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just embed the generator loop into another loop and use `taskwait` in between to ensure that all tasks have finished executing. You must also ensure proper locking of the linked list in the concurrent parts of the code, e.g. by the use of critical sections (as shown below) or finer-grained locks.

```c
doWork(element e)
{
   // ...
   #pragma omp critical(listOps)
   insertElement(linkedList, newElement);
   // ...
}

#pragma omp parallel
{
   #pragma omp single
   {
      do
      {
         #pragma omp critical(listOps)
         while (!empty(linkedList)) {
            element e = removeElement(linkedList);
            #pragma omp task
            doWork(e);
         }
         #pragma omp taskwait
      } while (!empty(linkedList));
   }
}
```